# set the execute bits in C

Tags: c

I am writing a program which requires me to create a file using standard `fopen fprintf fclose` calls.

I want to set the execute bits.

I can do this with `chmod` but this seems overkill. For the life of me (possibly due to advanced age) I can't seem to find (or remember) an API to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`chmod(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html) ***is*** an API call,
and is the canonical way of changing the mode of a file (referenced by name)
from a program; it is not overkill.

Comment: I wonder if the OP wasn't thinking of running the `chmod` program, rather than calling `chmod()`...

Comment: True; `system("chmod …")` would be inappropriate.

Comment: Duh! I was getting `chmod(1)` rather than `chmod(2)`

Answer (score 7):

[`fchmod(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html) would be in keeping with your other calls... Given a file descriptor in `fd`:

```
struct stat buf;
fstat(fd, &buf);
fchmod(fd, buf.st_mode | S_IXUSR | S_IXGRP | S_IXOTH);
```

will add all three execute bits to the file's current mode (error handling left as an exercise for the reader).

You'd use [`fileno(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html) to get the file descriptor from your `FILE *` structures. Alternatively you could use [`chmod(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html) and pass it the file name.

Comment: This is not really "in keeping with" the OP's other calls — `fopen`, `fprintf`, and `fclose`, etc., operate on file pointers (`FILE *fp`), whereas `fchmod` (as your example indicates) operates on a file *descriptor* (`int fd`).  If the OP has done `fp = fopen(…)`, then he would have to do `fchmod(fileno(fp), …)`.

Comment: I was thinking "as opposed to `chmod(2)` which is filename-based". If you've already got the file open you might as well use the file descriptor, even if that involves going through `fileno(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use fchmod (see fchmod(3)), or umask if you want to apply the same for every file created (extracts below taken from http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-Permissions.html and the [umask(2) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/umask)):

The functions in this section are declared in sys/stat.h.

Function: mode_t umask (mode_t mask)

The umask function sets the file creation mask of the current process to mask, and returns the previous value of the file creation mask.

```
Here is an example showing how to read the mask with umask without changing it permanently:

mode_t
read_umask (void)
{
  mode_t mask = umask (0);
  umask (mask);
  return mask;
}

However, on GNU/Hurd systems it is better to use getumask if you just want to read the mask value, because it is reentrant.
```

#### Name

umask - set file mode creation mask

`mode_t umask(mode_t mask);`

#### Description

umask() sets the calling process's file mode creation mask (umask) to mask & 0777 (i.e., only the file permission bits of mask are used), and returns the previous value of the mask.

The umask is used by open(2), mkdir(2), and other system calls that create files to modify the permissions placed on newly created files or directories. Specifically, permissions in the umask are turned off from the mode argument to open(2) and mkdir(2).

The constants that should be used to specify mask are described under stat(2).

The typical default value for the process umask is S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH (octal 022). In the usual case where the mode argument to open(2) is specified as:

```
S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH
```

(octal 0666) when creating a new file, the permissions on the resulting file will be:

```
S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH
```

(because 0666 & ~022 = 0644; i.e., rw-r--r--).
Return Value
This system call always succeeds and the previous value of the mask is returned

Comment: How does `umask` help the OP set the execute bit(s) on a file? `fopen` uses mode 0666 by default, and `umask` can only take away bits, not add them.